# Какие элементы С являются неподдерживаемыми в С++?

Tags: c, gcc, c++, g++

Какие элементы языка С являются неподдерживаемыми в С++? Какой код на С не будет принят компилятором С++? Особенно интересует поведение g++.

Comment: Не совсем понятен критерий "будет принят компилятором". Компиляторы С, согласно требованиям стандарта языка, при обнаружении "ошибки" в коде обязаны выдать диагностическое сообщение, после чего они имеют право продолжать компиляцию. Код при этом не считается кодом на С и его поведение с точки зрения языка С не определено. С компиляторами С++ дело обстоит в точности так же. Вот компилятор С обнаружил ошибку, выдал, как того требует стандарт, диагностическое сообщение, и пошел дальше  компилировать. Это как считать: "принял" или "не принял"?

Comment: @AnT может я чего-то не понял, раз Вы так удивляетесь, но в моем погимании «принят» — значит, выполнит компиляцию без ошибок, породит объектный код, в объёме, соответствующем исходникам.

Comment: @alexolut: Что такое "ошибка" в вашем понимании? Компилятопы типа GCC известны тем, что рапортуют языковые "ошибки", как "предупреждения". Такие "ошибки", отрапортованные как "предупреждения" - это "ошибки" или нет? Также это поведение зависит от настроек компилятора. О каком именно состоянии этих настроек вы говорите?

Comment: У ТС в вопросе указано про g++, логично предположить, что все возможные расширения и послабления его вполне бы устроили. К сожалению, он уже недостаточно активен на сайте, и мы вряд ли это узнаем в скором времени или вовсе.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Развитие C++ и C разделилось. У C++ выходит свой стандарт, у C - свой. C++ поддерживает все возможности C89, но не поддерживает более новые - C99 и C11. Конечно, это зависит от реализации компилятора, но в стандарт C++11 по-прежнему входят возможности только C89. Правда, в него добавили long long, который появился ещё в C99, и ещё пару возможностей.

Сам я новых возможностей C не знаю, так как использую C++, но, судя по википедии, в C99 есть следующие возможности, отсутствующие в C++:

1. Массивы переменной длины
2. Типовые математические функции (tgmath.h)
3. Проектируемые инициализаторы
4. Составные константы
5. Смягчение (restrict) ограничений для более агрессивной оптимизации кода

В C11:

1. Выражения, не зависящие от типа (Type-generic expressions) с использованием ключевого слова _Generic
2. Комплексные числа

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Можно поконкретнее?

Comment: Спасибо. Надо будет со всем этим ознакомиться. 

Хотя, мне кажется, в С++ тоже есть массивы переменной длины.

Comment: >Хотя, мне кажется, в С++ тоже есть массивы переменной длины.

 Я слышал, что в g++ есть, но это, по-моему, не по стандарту.

Answer (score 29):

Язык C существенно отличается от языка C++ с самого начала его существования. (Понятно, что новые свойства языка C99 позволяют нам запросто писать примеры C кода, который не будет компилироваться в C++, но на самом деле для этого совсем не обязательно обращаться к C99. Даже "классический" стандартный C - C89/90 - заметно отличается от C++.)

Серьезных отличий много, но согласно постановке вопроса нас интересуют только отличия, которые делают корректный C код некорректным в C++. Не претендуя на полноту, попробую перечислить эти отличия и привести примеры кода, опирающиеся на эти отличия. Ключевым моментом здесь является именно то, что использованные синтаксические конструкции присутствуют в обоих языках, т.е. с первого взгляда код выглядит достаточно невинно и с точки зрения языка C++.

1. В языке C разрешается "терять" замыкающий `'\0'` при инициализации массива символов строковым литералом

   ```
   char s[4] = "1234";
   ```

   Код некорректен с точки зрения C++.
2. C поддерживает "предварительные" (tentative) определения. В одной единице трансляции можно сделать множественные внешние определения одного и того же объекта

   ```
   /* На уровне файла */

   int a;
   int a;
   int a, a, a;
   ```

   Код некорректен с точки зрения C++.
3. В языке С typedef-имена типов и тэги struct-типов располагаются в разных пространствах имен и не конфликтуют друг с другом. Например, такой набор объявлений допустим в С

   ```
    struct A { int i; };
    typedef struct B { int i; } A;
    typedef struct C { int i; } C;
   ```

   В языке С++ не существует отдельного понятия "тэга" для класс-типов: имена классов разделяют одно пространство имен с typedef-именами и могут конфликтовать с ними. Для частичной обратной совместимости с кросс-компилируемым идиоматическим С кодом язык С++ разрешает объявлять typedef-псевдонимы, совпадающие с именами существующих класс-типов, но только при условии, что псевдоним ссылается именно на класс-тип с таким же именем.

   В вышеприведенном примере первое typedef-объявление некорректно с точки зрения C++.
4. В языке С "незнакомое" имя `struct` типа, упомянутое в списке параметров функции, является объявлением нового типа, *локального* для этой функции. При этом в списке параметров функции этот тип может быть объявлен как неполный, а "дообъявлен" до полного типа уже в теле функции

   ```
    /* Тип `struct S` в этой точке не известен */

    void foo(struct S *p)
    {
      struct S { int a; } s;

      p = &s;
      p->a = 5;
    }
   ```

   В этом коде все корректно с точки зрения языка С: `p` имеет тот же тип, что и `&s` и т.д.

   С точки зрения языка C++ упоминание "незнакомого" имени `struct` типа в списке параметров функции тоже является объявлением нового типа. Однако этот новый тип не является локальным: он считается принадлежащим *охватывающему пространству имен*. Поэтому с точки зрения языка C++ локальное определение типа `S` в вышеприведенном примере не имеет никакого отношения к типу `S`, упомянутому в списке параметров. Присваивание `p = &s` невозможно из-за несоответствия типов. Код некорректен с точки зрения C++.
5. C разрешает делать определения новых типов внутри оператора приведения типа, внутри оператора `sizeof`, в объявлениях функций (типы возвращаемого значения и типы параметров)

   ```
    int a = sizeof(enum E { A, B, C }) + (enum X { D, E, F }) 0;
    enum E e = B;
    int b = e + F;
   ```

   Код некорректен с точки зрения C++.
6. Язык С разрешает определять внешние объекты неполных типов при условии, что тип доопределяется и становится полным где-то дальше в этой же единице трансляции

   ```
    /* На уровне файла */

    struct S s;
    struct S { int i; };
   ```

   Вышеприведенный набор объявлений корректен с точки зрения С, но некорректен с точки зрения С++. Язык С++ безусловно запрещает определять объекты неполных типов.
7. В языке C многие statements создают свою неявную охватывающую область видимости в дополнение к уже существующей области видимости в "теле" этого statement, в то время как в C++ создается единая область видимости.

   Например

   ```
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
      int i = 42;
    }
   ```

   В языке C тело цикла является вложенной областью видимости по отношению к заголовку цикла, вследствие чего данный код является корректным. В C++ область видимости только одна, что исключает возможность "вложенного" объявления `i`.
8. Язык C разрешает прыжки через объявления с инициализацией

   ```
    switch (1)
    {
      int a = 42;
    case 1:;
    }
   ```

   Код некорректен с точки зрения C++.
9. В C вложенные объявления `struct` типов помещают имя внутреннего типа во внешнюю (охватывающую) область видимости

   ```
    struct A
    {
      struct B { int b; } a;
    };

    struct B b;
   ```

   Код некорректен с точки зрения C++.
10. C допускает неявное преобразование указателей из типа `void *`

    ```
     void *p = 0;
     int *pp = p;
    ```

    Код некорректен с точки зрения C++.
11. C поддерживает объявления функций без прототипов

    ```
     /* На уровне файла */

     void foo();

     void bar() 
     {
       foo(1, 2, 3);
     }
    ```

    Код некорректен с точки зрения C++.
12. В C значения типа `enum` свободно неявно преобразуемы к типу `int` и обратно

    ```
     enum E { A, B, C } e = A;
     e = e + 1;
    ```

    Код некорректен с точки зрения C++.
13. Неявно генерируемые компилятором C++ конструкторы копирования и операторы присваивания не умеют копировать `volatile` объекты. В C же копирование `volatile` объектов - не проблема

    ```
    struct S { int i; };
    volatile struct S v = { 0 };
    struct S s = v;
    ```

    Код некорректен с точки зрения C++.
14. В C строковые литералы имеют тип `char [N]`, а в C++ - `const char [N]`. Даже если считать, что "классический" C++ в виде исключения поддерживает преобразование строкового литерала к типу `char *`, это исключение работает только тогда, когда оно применяется *непосредственно* к строковому литералу

    ```
    char *p = &"abcd"[0];
    ```

    Код некорректен с точки зрения C++.
15. C допускает использование "бессмысленных" спецификаторов класса хранения в объявлениях, которые не объявляют объектов

    ```
    static struct S { int i; };
    ```

    Код некорректен с точки зрения C++.

    Дополнительно можно заметить, что в языке C `typedef` формально тоже является лишь одним из спецификаторов класса хранения, что позволяет создавать typedef-объявления, которые не объявляют псевдонимов

    ```
    typedef struct S { int i; };
    ```

    C++ не допускает таких typedef-объявлений.
16. С допускает явные повторения cv-квалификаторов в объявлениях

    ```
    const const int a = 42;
    ```

    Код некорректен с точки зрения C++. (С++ допускает аналогичную "избыточную" квалификацию, но только через посредство промежуточных имен типов: typedef-имена, параметры шаблонов).
17. В языке C любое целочисленное константное выражение со значением `0` может использоваться в качестве null pointer constant

    ```
    void *p = 2 - 2;
    void *q = -0;
    ```

    Так же обстояли дела и в C++ до принятия стандарта C++11. Однако в современном C++ из целочисленных значений только буквальное значение `0` (целочисленный литерал) может выступать в роли null pointer constant, а вот более сложные выражения более не являются допустимыми. Вышеприведенные инициализации некорректны с точки зрения C++.
18. В языке C вы можете сделать неопределяющее объявление объекта типа `void`

    ```
    extern void v;
    ```

    (Определение такого объекта сделать не получится, т.к. `void` - неполный тип). В C++ запрещается делать даже неопределяющее объявление.
19. В языке С битовое поле, объявленное с типом `int` без явного указания `signed` или `unsigned` может быть как знаковым, там и беззнаковым (определяется реализацией). В языке С++ такое битовое поле всегда является знаковым.
20. Препроцессор языка C не знаком с такими литералами как `true` и `false`. В языке C `true` и `false` доступны лишь как макросы, определенные в заголовочном файле `<stdbool.h>`. Если эти макросы не определены, то в соответствии с правилами работы препроцессора, как `#if true` так и `#if false` должно вести себя как `#if 0`.

    В то же время препроцессор языка C++ обязан нативно распознавать литералы `true` и `false` и его директива `#if` должна вести себя с этим литералами "ожидаемым" образом.

    Это может служить источником несовместимостей, когда в C-коде не произведено включение `<stdbool.h>`

    ```
    #if true
      int a[-1];
    #endif
    ```

    Данный код является заведомо некорректным в C++, и в то же время может спокойно компилироваться в C.
21. В языке С не поддерживается cv-квалификация для rvalues. В частности, cv-квалификация возвращаемого значения функции игнорируется языком. Вкупе с автоматическим преобразованием массивов к указателям, это позволяет обходить некоторые правила константной корректности

    ```
    struct S { int a[10]; };

    const struct S foo() { struct S s; return s; }

    int main()
    {
      int *p = foo().a;
    }
    ```

    С точки зрения языка C++ возвращаемое значение `foo()` и, следовательно, массив `foo().a` являются константными, и неявное преобразование `foo().a` к типу `int *` невозможно.
22. В языке С неявный конфликт между внутренним и внешним связыванием при объявлении одной и той же сущности приводит к неопределенному поведению, а в С++ такой конфликт делает программу ill-formed (ошибочной). Чтобы устроить такой неявный конфликт, надо выстроить довольно хитрую конфигурацию

    ```
    static int a; 
    /* Внутреннее связывание */

    void foo(void)
    {
      int a; 
      /* Скрывает внешнее static `a`, не имеет связывания */

      {
        extern int a; 
        /* Из-за того, что внешнее static `a` скрыто, объявляет `a` 
           с внешним связыванием. Теперь `a` объявлено и с внешним, 
           и с внутренним связыванием - конфликт */
      }
    }
    ```

    В С++ такое `extern`-объявление является ошибочным.
23. Рекурсивные вызовы функции `main` разрешены в C, но запрещены в C++.
24. Препроцессор языка C++ больше не рассматривает (C++11) последовательность `<строковый или символьный литерал><идентификатор>` как независимые токены. С точки зрения языка C++ `<идентификатор>` в такой ситуации является суффиксом литерала. Чтобы избежать такой интерпретации, в языке C++ эти токены следует разделять пробелом

    ```
    uint32_t a = 42;
    printf("%"PRIu32, a);
    ```

    Этот код корректен c точки зрения C, но некорректен с точки зрения C++.
25. Язык С допускает определение константных объектов без инициализации

    ```
    void foo()
    {
      const int a;
    }
    ```

    В C++ такое объявление является некорректным.
26. В языке С разрешается использовать имя поля, совпадающее с существующим именем типа

    ```
     typedef int I;

     struct S
     {
       I I;
     };
    ```

    В языке С++ такое "переопределение" идентификатора не допускается.

Comment: Поправка к пункту 8. Я не знаю, что Вы подразумеваете под 'прототип' (в учебниках, вроде бы как, 'прототип' - это и есть объявление функции. но руку за это не отдам :-) ), но по примеру - это объявление функции без указания аргументов. Такое объявление отключает проверку аргументов у функции при вызове, что позволяет делать всякие нехорошие вещи. Кроме этого, функции можно использовать вообще без объявления. В этом случае, компилятор сам выводит прототип из первого вызова функции, а возвращаемое значение считается `int`.

Comment: @Vladimir: У вас все задом наперед. *Прототипом* в С является объявление функции "в стиле С++", т.е. с явным указанием количества и типов аргументов. Например, `void foo(int, double);` - это объявление с прототипом. Объявление без указания аргументов (как у меня в 8) прототипом не является. О каком "возвращаемое значение считается int" вы ведете речь - не понятно совсем, ибо любое объявление функции - что с прототипом, что без  - всегда явно указывает тип возвращаемого значения.

Comment: Подозреваю, что вы ведете речь о возможности вызывать совсем не объявленные функции в С89/90. Но я об этой возможности решил не упоминать вообще, ибо она даже в С89/90 является устаревшей.

Comment: Да, именно из C89, я про них так и написал - совсем никак не объявленные.

Comment: @Vladimir: Ну, еще раз: возможность вызывать совсем не объявленные -  это отдельный пункт, которую я решил не включать в свой список.

Comment: Я бы в (10) дописал, что в сторону int'ов в С++ преобразование тоже есть. Еще, можете рассказать поподробнее про исключение в (12)? А то мой gcc `char *p = "abcd";` [не компилирует](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f745ff58dba5d088).

Comment: @olyBlackCat: Это исключение существовало в С++98 и С++03, но уже с самого начала являлось deprecated. В С++11 его убрали из языка окончательно. Поэтому в С++ `char *p = "abcd";` больше не компилируется.

Comment: Если не трудно, можете дать почитать что-нибудь про (14)?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat : Моя изначальная формулировка была некорректной. Различие есть, но заключается одно в другом и детали тоже несколько иные. Я исправил 14. Это различие - не такое уж и интересное :) Причем GCC в режиме С рапортует это как ошибку, хотя на самом деле это неопределенное поведение (рапортовать неопределенное поведение как ошибку допустимо). Нужна ли доп.иноформация по этому варианту?

Comment: @AnT *"Нужна ли доп.иноформация"* Теперь нет. :) В отредактированном варианте все понятно.

Comment: @Vladimir немного описывал здесь о "функциях без параметров"  (правда, про прототипы не упоминал)https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/859679/void-как-параметр/859857#859857

Comment: Мощно. А если еще добавить [гнусные расширения](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html#C-Extensions) (nested functions, labels as values, ...) ...

Comment: Про `20` пункт `MinGW` говорит: **error: variable previously declared 'static' redeclared 'extern'**

Comment: В Си++ константные переменные по умолчанию имеют статическую область линковки *(видимости)* **static** ,  в Си внешнюю **extern**. Можете проверить и добавить.

Comment: @AlexGebe: это хорошо известно. Но меня, в данном случае интересовали в первую очередь примеры, которые проявляют себя в рамках одной единицы трансляции, то есть на уровне препроцессора или компилятора в узком смысле слова. Отличия, проявляющиеся только на уровне линкера, меня интересовали меньше.

Comment: индивидуальная инициализация в структурах и массивах : `struct S {int a,b,c,y,x;};struct S x={ . x = 0 , . y = 1 } ;` и `int arr[100]={ [77]=33 , [33]=77};` - добавите?

Comment: @AlexGlebe: Во-первых, это - "очевидное" отличие С99, т.е. оно не соответствует моим критериям выбора. Во-вторых, индивидуальная инициализация в структурах появится в С++23.

Answer (score 14):

А зачем вам это надо? Если у вас есть C-код, так компилируйте его как C. Если надо использовать C++, то компилируйте разными компиляторами, а потом линкуйте отдельно. Не забудьте про extern "C" только, иначе линковка закончится ошибкой.

**UPD**

Если подумать чисто теоретически, то главной проблемой наверняка станет недостаточно строгая проверка типов в С, которую не потерпит С++. С++ в отношении типов более строгий.

**UPD2**

И да, в С можно, например, вызывать необъявленные функции с неправильными аргументами. Ясно что С++ такое зарубит в тот же момент.

Comment: Интерес больше теоретический, чем практический

Comment: "Недостаточно строгая проверка типов в С" сводится фактически к возможности делать неявное преобразование из `void *` к другим указательным типам и к совместимости `enum` и `int` в С. Во всех остальных отношениях строгость проверки типов С не отличается от строгости проверки типов в С++.

Answer (score 13):

Хороший вопрос. Всегда писал на с и избегал с++.

Вот этот код (только не помню, зачем он, но компилируется gcc и работает) не компилируется g++.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <time.h>

main ()
{
  int c, i = 0;
  char c4[5];
  clock_t t = clock();
  unsigned short *u = L"12345\0AРђР‘\n";

  for (i = 0; u[i] != '\n'; i++)
    printf ("u[%d] = %d (%x)\n",i,u[i],u[i]);

  printf ("start %d %d\n",CLOCKS_PER_SEC,t);
  i = 0;
  while ((c = getch()) != 26 ) { // ^Z text stdin EOF 
    printf ("%d %d\n",CLOCKS_PER_SEC,clock());
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') {
      putchar(c);  fflush(stdout);
      c4[i++] = c;
    }
    if (c == '\b') {  // BS == 8
      printf ("\b \b");  fflush(stdout);
      if (--i < 0)
    i = 0;
      continue;
    }
    if (c == '\r' || i == 4) { // ENTER or Your 4 digits
      c4[i] = 0;
      printf ("\nMy %d digits: %s\n",i,c4);
      i = 0;
    }
  }
  clock_t t1 = clock();
  printf ("%d %d\n",CLOCKS_PER_SEC,t1);

}
```

MinGW g++ (GCC) 3.4.5 (mingw-vista special r3) в Windows XP

g++ -c t1.c

пишет:

```
t1.c: In function `int main()':
t1.c:11: error: invalid conversion from `const wchar_t*' to `short unsigned int*'
t1.c:18: error: `getch' was not declared in this scope
```

Так что, с точки зрения практики, [@cy6erGn0m](/users/335/cy6ergn0m) Вам все правильно сказал.

Comment: Да, скорее всего, одно из отличий - более жесткая политика с неявным приведением типов. И это правильно, товарищи. gcc  для данного кода просто выдает предупреждение. Но если явно привести тип, то g++ нормально все компилирует. Но я и в С стараюсь явно приводить типы.

Comment: У меня gcc никаких предупреждений для этого кода не выдает.

Comment: Я компилировал в Ubuntu gcc 4.4. Дело в том, что в нем тип wchar_t определен как typedef int wchar_t ( в С). Поэтому предупреждает:

warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type

В С++ wchar_t является встроенным типом, а С++ запрещает присвоение значения указателя одного типа указателю другого типа без явного приведения.

Comment: Да, 4.4 более строгий.

Comment: народ, а как он у вас реагирует на эту строчку

    #include <windows.h>

???

Comment: В виндовсе положительно, в лине отрицательно

Answer (score 9):

Кроме всего вышеназванного, бывает, что попытка скомпилировать код `C` в `C++` заканчивается ошибками из-за `malloc`, точнее из-за возможности соответствующей записи с `void*` в `C` и невозможности в `C++`:

```
// C
int* a = malloc(24 * sizeof(int));

// C++ (можно использовать и C-style каст)
int* a = static_cast<int*>(malloc(24 * sizeof(int));)
```

*Но вообще, да - компилируйте отдельно соответствующим компилятором и линкуйтесь.* Тем более, что, например, `C` библиотеки, собранные с помощью `gcc`, `icc` и `cl`,  в 99% случаев совместимы.

Comment: Спасибо, опять же дело упирается в более жесткую политику С++ в отношении приведения типов указателей.

А раздельная компиляция - любимое развлечение )))

Comment: @skegg: "Политики" в отношении приведения типов указателей совершенно идентичны в С и в С++, за исключением возможности неявного приведения из `void *` в С. Именно на это исключение и опирается данный пример.

Answer (score 8):

Замечательный вопрос. Действительно, C не является подмножеством C++. Помимо хрестоматийного примера с приведением void* к типизированному указателю, есть ряд более редких, но иногда очень неприятных моментов.

Вот код, который без ошибок обрабатывается компилятором gcc (в том числе с ключом --pedantic):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int plus();

int main()
{
    printf("%d\n", plus(5, 7));
    return 0;
}

int plus(int a, int b)
{
    return a + b;
}
```

Однако при компиляции g++ имеем:

```
user@linux:~> g++ test.c
test.c: In function ‘int main()’:
test.c:7:27: error: too many arguments to function ‘int plus()’
test.c:3:5: note: declared here
```

Компилятор C в соответствии со стандартом трактует пустой список параметров в прототипе функции `plus()` как *неопределенный*, компилятор C++ - как *пустой*. Только при вызове компилятора C с ключом `-Wall` можно лицезреть предупреждение.

Разумеется, любые соглашения о стиле кодирования должны исключать пустые прототипы, поскольку компилятор лишается возможности проверки соответствия сигнатур типов, то есть в приведенном примере можно написать `plus(5, 7, 9)` вместо `plus(5, 7)` и компилятор прожует.

Comment: В каком параграфе стандарта описано правило трактовки пустого списка параметров? Давно хотел почитать про этом подробно, но что-то так и не смог найти.

Answer (score 4):

gсс (на данный момент 7.3) в режиме с++ все еще не поддерживает некоторых способов инициализации структур/объединений/перечислений, которые поддерживаются в режиме с:

```
struct array_s {
    union { // в объединении C++ может инициализироваться первый элемент
        struct {
            uint16_t af;
            uint16_t bf;
        };
        uint32_t sign;
    };
    uint16_t  rows;
    uint16_t  cols;
    void     *data;
};

#ifdef __cplusplus
    struct array_s a = {{{1, 2} }, 100, 200 }; // c++
//    struct array_s a = {{{0x20001}}, 100, 200 };
#else
    struct array_s b = {{ .af = 1, .bf = 2 }, .cols = 200, .rows = 100}; // c
#endif
```

Поскольку, инициализация объединения в работает только для первого члена, в вышеприведенном случае это анонимная структура, инициализацию sign вместо структуры классическим способом выполнить невозможно ни в с, ни в с++. 
Однако это можно сделать в c11, как это показано выше. В c++ мы получаем ошибку:

```
error: too many initializers for 'array_s'
sorry, unimplemented: non-trivial designated initializers not supported
```