# Void как параметр

Tags: c++

Чем отличается объявление функции

```
int main(){}
```

От

```
int main(void){}
```

?

Вроде все то же самое, но часто попадается в исходниках последнее. Если нет разницы, зачем писать лишнее?

Comment: Может вы С++ с С перепутали, где это не одно и то же?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
void foo(void);
```

Это правильный путь объявления функции без параметров в С, С++.

С другой стороны:

```
void foo();
```

Имеет разное значение в С и С++! В С это означает "может принимать любое количество параметров неизвестных типов", в С++ имеет тот же смысл что и `foo(void)`.

Функции с переменным количеством аргументов по своей сути являются небезопасными, и их следует избегать, когда это только возможно.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/693794/6677992)

Comment: Только не "нестандартными", а скорее "небезопасными".

Comment: я понял, там параметры через стэк передаются. По идее функции с переменным количеством параметров более медленные

Comment: @HolyBlackCat sprintf

Comment: @ЕвгенийБорисов Это вы к чему?

Comment: Пример качественной функции с переменным количеством аргументов

Answer (score 3):

Предлагаю разобраться с подобным синтаксисом.

В языке C функция может быть объявлена как

> **6.7.6.3  Function declarators (including prototypes**
>
> 5. If, in the declaration "T D1",D1 has the form
>      `D(parameter-type-list)`
>      or
>      `D(identifier-list_opt)`

Как видим, у нас имеется два варианта объявления:

1. В скобках `parameter-type-list`
2. В скобках `identifier-list`

При этом `parameter-type-list` является обязательным, а `identifier-list` является опциональным (`_opt`).

Теперь взглянем на то, что же такое `identifier-list`:

> 14. An identifier list declares only the identifiers of the parameters of the function. An empty list in a function declarator that is part of a definition of that function specifies that the function has no parameters. The empty list in a function declarator that is not part of a definition of that function specifies that no information about the number or types of the parameters is supplied.

То есть функция с `identifier-list` это вот такое объявление:

```
void foo(a, b, c) int a, b, c;//Функция объявлена с identifier-list
```

При этом такое объявление не накладывает ограничений на тип и количество параметров при вызове. Также, такой список является опциональным, т.е. может отсутствовать.

```
void foo();//Функция с пустым identifier-list
```

А это значит, что при вызове такой функции можно передавать параметры разных типов в разном количестве, т.е. вызовы `foo()` или `foo(1, 2)` являются законными.

Перейдем к `parameter-type-list`:

> 6. A parameter type list specifies the types of, and may declare identifiers for, the parameters of the function.

это **список типов** параметров, и, **возможно, идентификаторов**:

```
void foo(char, int, float x);//Функция объявлена с parameter-type-list
```

Смотрим стандарт далее:

> 10. The special case of an unnamed parameter of type void as the only item in the list specifies that the function has no parameters.

То есть имеется специальный случай для объявления функции не принимающей параметров - один параметр типа `void` без имени:

```
void foo(void);//Функция без параметров
```

Для такой функции вызов `foo(1, 2)` уже не является правильным, в отличии от ситуации с `identifier-list`.

Теперь, что касается C++. В C++ имеется один вариант объявления функции:

> 2. In a declaration `T D` where `D` has the form
>      `D1 ( parameter-declaration-clause ) cv-qualifier-seq_opt ref-qualifier_opt noexcept-specifier_opt attribute-specifier-seq_opt trailing-return-type`

При этом имеется правило:

> 4. ... If the parameter-declaration-clause is empty, the function takes no arguments. A parameter list consisting of a single unnamed parameter of non-dependent type void is equivalent to an empty parameter list.

То есть для C++ объявления

```
void foo();
void foo(void);
```

полностью эквивалентны.

И немного истории. Выдержка из книги Бьёрна Страуструпа "Дизайн и эволюция C++":

> В `C with Classes` введена нотация `f(void)` для функции `f()`, не принимающей аргументов, вместо нотации `f()` в `C`, обозначающей функцию с любым числом аргументов без проверки типов. Однако вскоре пользователи убедили меня, что нотация `f(void)` неизящна, а объявление с помощью `f()` функции, которая может принимать аргументы, далеко от интуитивно очевидного. Поэтому после некоторых экспериментов было решено оставить нотацию `f()` для функции, не принимающей никаких аргументов, ибо именно этого ожидает неискушенный пользователь. Чтобы отважиться на такой разрыв с традициями `C`, мне потребовалась поддержка со стороны *Дуга Макилроя и Денниса Ритчи*. Только после того как они охарактеризовали нотацию `f(void)` словом "гадость", я решил придать `f()` очевидную семантику. Однако и по сей день правила контроля типов в `C` гораздо слабее чем в `C++`, а комитет по стандартизации `ANSI C` одобрил "отвратительную `f(void)`", впервые появившуюся в `C with Classes`.

Comment: Интересно, спасибо )

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы компилятор не ругался, по стандарту, должны быть описаны параметры принимаемые функцией, если их нет то `void` - пусто/отсутствие параметров.

Попробуйте собрать код без `void` с ключами `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic`, для `C` языка полезен ключ `-Wstrict-prototypes` (gcc или clang) и увидите реакцию компилятора.

Вероятно будет полезно ознакомиться с [ключами компилятора](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), чтоб получать больше информации о собственном коде.

например важные ключи для анализа собственного кода:

**-Wall**

> Включите все предупреждения о конструкциях, которые некоторые
>   пользователи считают сомнительными, и которые легко избежать (или
>   изменить для предотвращения предупреждения), даже в сочетании с
>   макросами, другими словами, некоторый набор предупреждений.

**-Wpedantic**

> Выдать все предупреждения, требуемые строгими ISO C и ISO C ++;
>   отклонить все программы, которые используют запрещенные расширения, и
>   некоторые другие программы, которые не соответствуют ISO C и ISO C ++.

**-Wextra**

> более полный тест собираемого кода, включены максимально возможные
>   предупреждения, но некоторые предупреждения задаются только индивидуально.

**-Weverything**

> специфический флаг компилятора `clang`, после его включения иногда возникает желание удалить написанное :)

**-Werror**
**-pedantic-errors**

> `-Werror` выдает ошибку, когда обнаружено предупреждение, переводит `warnings` в `errors`, 
>   `-pedantic-errors` соответственно делает тоже самое, только для предупреждений доступных в `-pedantic` mode.

Историческая справка:

> Первоначально C-функции не имели прототипов, поскольку `C`
>   эволюционировал из [`B`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B_%28programming_language%29), беспристрастного языка :) .
>   Когда были добавлены прототипы, оригинальные декларации без текста были оставлены на языке для обратной совместимости.

Comment: Типа что бы писатель уточнил что параметров действительно нет, а не он "забыл" какие хотел параметры.

Comment: А почему `-Werror` и `-pedantic-errors` слеплены вместе? Это далеко не одно и то же. `-Werror` переводит все warnings в errors. `-pedantic-errors` переводит в errors только те warnings, которые на самом деле являются errors с точки зрения языка.

Comment: `-Wall -Wextra` не включает все возможные предупреждения. Немалое количество предупреждений может быть включено только индивидуально.

Comment: Опция `-Wstrict-prototypes` неприменима при компиляции С++ кода. Поэтому ваш совет не ясен. В любом случае, никакой реакции компилятора тут получить не получится.

Comment: Я в общем написал :) подробный обзор ключей gcc есть по ссылке, а это коротенький бриф для облегчения понимания. Когда/если автор будет применять эти ключи, то  сориентируеться, когда и что работает. Имхо.. Главное дать направление, если тема ему интересна, разбереться.

Comment: Что-то я не вижу никакой реакции: https://godbolt.org/g/1FwEw9