# Компиляция программы, написанной на C, компилятором C++

Tags: c++, c

Я программирую на языке C примерно с октября. Сейчас я приступил к изучению языка C++. Я нашёл в интернете [хорошую статью](https://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B8%2B%2B/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%A1%D0%B8%2B%2B_%D0%BE%D1%82_%D0%A1%D0%B8) на тему "Основные отличия языка программирования C++ от языка C". Мой вопрос заключается в том, если я скомпилирую исходный код, написанный на языке C, компилятором `gcc` (C++), меняя при этом в коде только явное приведение некоторых типов (например, так:

```
char *k = malloc(x * sizeof(char)); //код на C
char *k = (char *) malloc(x * sizeof(char)); //код на C++
```

и не меняя практически больше ничего (в том числе **не меняя** библиотеку стандартного ввода и вывода `stdio.h` на `iostream`), будет ли данный код успешно выполняться? Или есть какие-то вещи, которые строго должны быть написаны на языке C++ по-другому в отличие от C? Насколько я знаю, язык C++ имеет строгий синтаксис. К примеру, я в статье прочитал, что в C++ немного по-другому объявляются указатели, так же используется какая-то функция `vector` вместо `malloc` / `realloc` / `calloc`, и так далее. Если я не буду этого учитывать и всё-равно буду пользоваться функцией `malloc`, например, то будет ли такая программа, скомпилированная на языке С++ *успешно* работать?

Возможно, мой вопрос некорректный и слегка глуп, нужно срочно разобраться именно с языком программирования C++ на основе знаний языка C для выполнения некоторой задачи в ближайшее время.

Comment: gcc это С компилятор. С++ компилирует g++.

Comment: @mrFieldy, да, я знаю. Это компилятор языка C++.

Comment: нет, компилятор gcc компилирует только С код. С++ код компилирует компилятор g++ из того же тулчейна. Это я так, к слову.

Comment: @mrFieldy, прошу прощения, запутался. Значит `gcc` - компилятор языка C, `g++` - компилятор языка C++, верно?

Comment: Формально С частично является подмножеством языка С++ и при использовании строго этого подмножества программа на С будет компилироваться и работать на С++. Есть мнение, что умение использовать именно это подмножество необходимо для полноценного владения языком С. Другое дело, что из-за организационных проблем С и С++ становятся все менее согласованными.

Comment: @nick да, совершенно верно.

Comment: Если ваш компилятор С++, то ваш код на С будет успешно выполняться. Если что и не выполняется, можете сами согласовать компановку. Например:   extern "C"  void* strlen(const char*);  Здесь    extern "C" какраз и есть соглашение о компановке

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/35502/Какие-элементы-С-являются-неподдерживаемыми-в-С/789069#789069

Comment: Вообще-то идея программировать на С++ как на С - как минимум странная. Пишите себе на С, и используйте при необходимости написанное на С в программе на С++, кто мешает? Пока что не встречал компилятора, который бы умел работать с С++, но не с С :) И еще - из вашего вопроса вытекает, что вы планируете использовать С++ просто как "улучшенный С", а это подход, как мне представляется,  не совсем верный. У С++ другой взгляд на жизнь, не такой, как у С :)

Answer (score -3):

Вместо malloc/free из C в C++ используются new/new[]/delete/delete[]. Поэтому просто так указанный в вопросе код с malloc C++ компилятором компилироваться не будет, нужно подключить заголовочный файл cstdlib. Но работать программа должна благополучно, если скомпилируется. C++ обратно совместим с C в основном.

В принципе узнать это можно было просто запустив `g++ -o main main.cpp`

Comment: Если у автора `malloc`/`free` работают в С, значит уже подключен `stdlib.h`. А он будет работать и в С++.