# Нужно ли дублировать static в определении функции?

Tags: c, функции, static

Правильно ли я понимаю, что если функция объявлена со спецификатором `static`, то его не надо дублировать в определении?

```
static void f(void);

void f(void)
{
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, не надо. Более того, даже если вы ее ниже явно объявите как `extern`, она все равно останется `static`

```
static void f(void);

extern void f(void) // Все равно функция имеет внутреннее связывание
{
    // ...
}
```

В стандарте языка (**6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers**) собственно поведение объявления без явного спецификатора класса хранения (ваше `void foo(void)`) по определению эквивалентно ему же с спецификатором `extern` (как у меня) (6.2.2/5). А поведение объявления с `extern` в свою очередь наследуется из того, что было объявлено выше (6.2.2/4).

Comment: Большое спасибо за помощь. Не подскажите, в каком параграфе стандарта искать описание этого процесса?

Comment: @MGNeo: **6.2.2 Linkages of identifiers**

Comment: В последнем пункте указанного параграфа сказано, что если в одной единице трансляции для идентификатора указано и внешнее, и внутреннее связывание, то поведение не определено. Я попытался это воспроизвести, но мне так и не удалось, поскольку компилятор считает мои варианты ошибкой. Что же имеется в виду?

Comment: @MGNeo: Пункт 20 вот здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/789069/182825. Но как вы сами там же и заметили, многие компиляторы С рапортуют это как ошибку. Это нормально. Неопределенное поведение допускает отказ от компиляции.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь.