# Как получить длину LPBYTE

Tags: c++, winapi

Есть переменная

```
LPBYTE a = (BYTE*)("A");
```

Как я могу получить её размер,есть-ли что то вроде `lstrlenA` только для LPBYTE?

Comment: то есть вы хотите узнать длину строки, на которую указывает `a`?

Comment: `LPBYTE` — это указатель на абстрактные бинарные данные. их длина должна хранится где-то отдельно.

Comment: но если это строка или что то, что оканчивается нулем - просто закастить к char и strlen и напарники.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LPBYTE` - *Long Pointer to Byte* (длинный указатель на тип byte)

Указатели в Си все имеют одинаковую длину, разница может если в ОС есть разделение на длинные, средние и короткие указатели (сейчас таких ОС уже почти нет по моему).

Самый верный способ вызвать:

```
LPBYTE a = (BYTE*)("A");
int size_of_a = sizeof(a);
```

Comment: Вопрос же с меткой [tag:c++]

Comment: И что? Кресты разве не поддерживают весь арсенал С?

Comment: [Какие элементы С являются неподдерживаемыми в С++?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/35502/398802)

Answer (score 0):

Если вы гарантируете, что конец данных по этому указателю = \0, тогда можете воспользоваться [strlen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strlen)